# Reg plus (+ amount) symbol displaying for user

Tags: custom

I have configured a simple product and the configuration is as below

100 gm - MRP 44 150 gm - MRP 62
I used the custom option(when adding a product) and added the price, base price was set for 100 gm as MRP 44 and for 150 gm i have configured the +18.Now in the front end its is displaying as

100 gm 150 gm +₹18.00
Is there a way i can hide the +₹18.00 so that users doesn't see this?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a mess, but when I understand correctly you want to hide the "+₹18".

This is rendered via JS in `Product.Config.getOptionLabel` in `js/varien/product.js:400`

You can change this by either changing the JS code here or somewhere up/down the call stack or by changing the PHTML/PHP code somewhere around

```
// app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml:37
var optionsPrice = new Product.OptionsPrice(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
```

Comment: Thank you..yes this is what i was looking for.will come back if i have further quries.

Comment: Please mark this answer as solution if it is. And vote it up if you like it.

Comment: I tried your suggestion..but not able to proceed further..can you pl help me with the actual code to be used if possible?Thanks much

Comment: What is your problem? Did you find the code snippet? You need to change the getJsonConfig().